# Google says the code is invalid, Where is my mistake?

Tags: javascript

```
var movie = [
    {
      title: "Iron Man",
      hasWatched: true,
      rating: "5.0",
    },
    {
      title: "Mad Max",
      hasWatched: false,
      rating: "2.0",
    }
]
```

Google says it is unable to read the property hasWatched in the following block of code

```
function buildString (movie){
    var result = "You have ";
    if(movie.hasWatched){ 
        result += "watched ";
    } else {
        result += "not watched ";
    }
    result += "\"" + movie.title + "\" - ";
    result += movie.rating + " stars"
    return result;
}

movie.forEach(function(movie){
    buildString();
    console.log(buildString(movie));
});
```

Comment: inside the `forEach` you're calling `buildString();` without arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
movie.forEach(function(movie){
buildString(movie);
console.log(buildString(movie));
});
```

> You have missed passing argument to the buildString() function.